# How to query database after the server has started?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to Query my database after the server has started, all of the tutorials on youtube write the code inside the server and run it. I don't want this, on [the official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/) they execute the commands inside a shell. How do I do the same?

Comment: Hi J.Doe, you seem pretty new to Stack Overflow. I really suggest editing your question to be clearer and more specific. This [meta post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) gives great guidance on how to ask a good question here.

Comment: Also, I think you might be looking for `manage.py dbshell`. If that doesn't work, then I would do a major overhaul to your question.

Comment: I tried your command and received the following error. "ImportError: No module named 'environ''

Answer (score 1):

the Django docs that you mentioned here [making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/) is using interactive  Python shell configured for your Django project, to access that you can run the following command

```
python manage.py shell
```

from there you can access  all those commands